# Wifi internet sharing via router

Tags: networking, router

I have the following scenario.

I have a laptop with wifi internet . I connected my laptop to Netgear router via ethernet cable.
I want to get the laptop wifi internet to be shared with those who connect to router.
Is it possible.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, rather than using a router (Netgear router), you should have used switch.
Now, since you have used a router, you have to write a **static route** in your netgear router which would say **0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0** (a packet heading towards internet) have to go to the IP address which is configured on the interface of your laptop where you have plugged Ethernet cable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got it via windows wifi properties-> sharing and now the devices which is connected to the router gets the internet

Comment: You're welcome. All thanks to the user-friendly options manufacturers provide nowadays!